Using setInterval to check time of data and then remove from object once expired; experiencing performance issues
I have a child component that I am attempting to render and check to see if a time attribute has expired.
The data and setData are props from my parent component.
The setInterval allows for the count down timer to work as expected, however, when an expired event is filtered and then updated in my setData it removes the item from object, but when displayed in the browser the new first item in the object will show time of 0s and then return to it's appropriate time remaining.
Here is the markup for my child component:
function Item({ item, data, setData }) {

     useEffect(() => {
        const endTime = new Date(item.endTime);
        const itemID = item.itemId;

        const timeCheck = (endTime, itemID) => {

            let time = new Date();
    
            let ending = Math.floor(parseInt(endTime) - (time.getTime()/1000));
            let minutes = Math.floor(ending / 60);
            let seconds = ending % 60;
    
            if (minutes < 60 && minutes >=1 ) {
                setEndingTime(minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");
            } else if (minutes === 0) {
                setEndingTime(seconds + "s");
            }
            
            if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
                //console.log(itemID);
                //console.log(data);
                let newData = data.filter(item => item.itemId !== itemID);
                setData(newData);
            }
            //console.log(minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");
        }

        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            timeCheck(endTime.getTime()/1000, itemID)
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [item, data, setData]);

    return(
                    <div className="item__time">
                        Time Left: { endingTime }
                    </div>
    )
}

export default Item;

The parent component:
function Tab({ setLoading }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getItems = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await fetch(‘local.api/endpoint’);
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error", error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems();
    }, []);

    return(
            <div className="tab">
                {data.length > 0 &&
                    data.map((item, index) => {
                        return(
                            <Item item={ item } data={ data } setData={ setData } key={`item__${ index }`} />
                        )
                    })
                }
          </div>
    )
}

export default Tab;

Any thoughts on what may be causing the rendering issues?

I think this code is incomplete - it appears to be missing the [endingTime, setEndingTime] state.

It's hard to say without seeing complete code and running it myself, but I suspct the problem is in your use of key here:
<Item item={ item } data={ data } setData={ setData } key={`item__${ index }`} />

Keys in React should give a unique, stable identifier for each item, so it can match components with their state. For simple cases, or for list contents that don't really change, you can get away with using the list index; however, for more complex cases, using an index can cause problems. Here, for example, something like the following is probably happening:

The initial list is rendered with itemA at index 0 / key 0, itemB at index 1 / key 1.
itemA is rendered in an <Item/>, which initializes its state, fires its effect, etc., as desired.
Once itemA's <Item/>'s timer goes to 0, it removes itemA from the list.
The list is rerendered - and now itemB is at index 0 / key 0.
In other words, instead of itemB's key 1 <Item/> being rendered at a new spot in the list, itemA's key 0 <Item/> is rerendered using itemB. It keeps any state it previously had (for example, its already expired time). Because its item has changed, it re-fires its effect, causing it to re-initalize its timer.

If you change your key to key={item.itemId}, things should work. (You don't need to worry about stuff like an item__ prefix - React needs keys to be stable and unique within a single list but otherwise really doesn't care about the format or string vs. number.)

Thank you. This was absolutely the solution and I can't believe for everything I had tried, I overlooked this approach.
